# Nodejs - qr Image doesn't load properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

i used the answer of this question
[Nodejs - How to show qr-image result in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27490742/nodejs-how-to-show-qr-image-result-in-view?newreg=9caf0a068a194dc2a11fb609eb709a72)

server-side i got:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var qr = require('qr-image');

router.get('/qrimage/:text', function(req,res){
  var code = qr.image(req.params.text, { type: 'png'});
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'image/png');
  res.pipe(code);
  res.end();
});
```

client-side with jQuery:

```
var thisUserName = 'bobby';
$.get('/users/qrimage/'+ thisUserName);
var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'users/qrimage/'+ thisUserName).load(function() {
        $("#qrim").replaceWith(img);
});
```

the client-side code will be executed, when you click on a link.
My problem is that the browser gets something but the image is not displayed properly.

console on click:

```
GET /users/qrimage/bobby 200 67.484 ms - -
```

Answer (score 1):

`qr.image()` returns a Readable stream. You're trying to pipe your response to it instead of the other way around. Try this:

```
router.get('/qrimage/:text', function(req,res){
  var code = qr.image(req.params.text, { type: 'png'});
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  code.pipe(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the DOM manipulation code into a `done` block after you run `$.get()`.

```
var thisUserName = 'bobby';
$.get('/users/qrimage/'+ thisUserName)
.done(function(data) {  
  // data will be the result of the server code.
})
.fail(function() {
  // something went wrong
});
```

Also, as mscdex pointed out, you've got your pipe and stream log backwards.

Comment: how can i display the image in the done block with the data variable?

Comment: You'll have to create a new image and set it's src attribute to the result assuming the result is base64 string.